# Extjs add event to a button in a grid form the controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've added a toolbar to my grid
I'm not able to bind the event in  the controller/controll
It's boring have to right when the code explain itself :)

```
Ext.define('SA.view.user.List' ,{
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias : 'widget.userlist',
  title : 'All Users',
  store: 'Users',
  initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [
      {
      header: 'Id',
      sortable: true,
      dataIndex: 'id',
      flex: 1,
      field: {
        type: 'textfield'
      }
    },
    {
      header: 'Name',
      sortable: true,
      dataIndex: 'uname',
      flex: 1,
      field: {
        type: 'textfield'
      }
    },
    {
      header: 'Email',
      sortable: true,
      dataIndex: 'email',
      flex: 1,
      field: {
        type: 'textfield'
      }
    }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
  },

  dockedItems: [
    {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    items: [{
      iconCls: 'icon-add',
      text: 'Add',
      scope: this

    }, {
      iconCls: 'icon-delete',
      text: 'Delete',
      disabled: true,
      itemId: 'delete',
      scope: this

    }]
  },
  {
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store: 'Users',   // same store GridPanel is using
    dock: 'bottom',
    displayInfo: true
  }
  ]
});
```

How can handler the click event form within the controller

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'userlist': {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser
        },
        'userlist > toolbar/*my attempt but it doesnt work :( */': {
            click: this.insertUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateUser
        }
    });
},
```

Bye

Comment: I've done a trick :) xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    iconCls: 'icon-add',
                    id: 'b-add',
                    text: 'Add',
                    scope: this
                   
                } 'userlist > toolbar > button#b-add'

Comment: It's not a good idea. Using strict ids is bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can change it like this

```
dockedItems: [
    {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    items: [{
      iconCls: 'icon-add',
      text: 'Add',
      action: 'add',
      scope: this

    }, {
      iconCls: 'icon-delete',
      text: 'Delete',
      action: 'delete',
      disabled: true,
      itemId: 'delete',
      scope: this

    }]
  },


init: function() {
    this.control({
        'userlist': {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser
        },
        'userlist button[action=add]': {
            click: this.insertUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateUser
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `userlist button[text=Delete]': { click: this.insertUser }` or `userlist button[itemId=delete]': { click: this.insertUser }`.

This selectors are similiar to those from CSS, so usually you'll use `container > child_subcontainer another_subcontainer element[property=value]`. Underneath controller uses [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery), so you may want play with it to check what it can.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the action part will also work.

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'userlist': {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser
        },
        'userlist > toolbar > button[action=add]': {
            click: this.insertUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateUser
        }
    });
},
```